# Getting Error 10054 after renaming the server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, connectivity

[image: screenshot of error message when connecting through SSMS]

When I open SQL Server I have error 10054. Recently I changed the server name and I probably have this problem since. How can I solve it?

Comment: Did you restart sql server service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have tried all the options there are and  still doesnt  work for you 
and only if it is on your private computer reinstall sql
Then everything will work well

Link to free sql installation:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

good luck!!!

Answer (score 4):

See the Microsoft Docs article [Rename a Computer that Hosts a Stand-Alone Instance of SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/rename-a-computer-that-hosts-a-stand-alone-instance-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

You'll need to restart the SQL Server service, and use `sp_dropserver` / `sp_addserver` to update the server name within SQL Server.

Comment: Try to login using single mode you should be able to log in to the instance, assuming you're administrator on the server. 
https://www.sqlshack.com/different-ways-to-start-a-sql-server-single-user-mode/

Comment: @I'm I see.  Can you log in to the server itself and restart the service?  Or remotely restart the machine?

Comment: i can log in to the server itsel but what to do and how?

Comment: @I'm If no one can connect to it, then go to Windows Services and restart the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service.  This should let you connect through SSMS once it comes back up.  Then you can follow the other instructions in the docs article.